# Exact match a field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In each of the documents I am indexing I have a field called "permalink" which I would like to exact match on.

An example document:

```
{
    "entity_type": "company",
    "entity_id": 1383221763,
    "company_type": "developer",
    "name": "Runewaker Entertainment",
    "permalink": "runewaker-entertainment"
}
```

The mapping for these documents is:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "entity_id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "include_in_all": false
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "include_in_all": true,
        },
        "permalink": {
            "type": "string",
            "include_in_all": true,
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "company_type": {
            "type": "string",
            "include_in_all": false,
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the following query then I don't get any hits:

```
POST /companies/company/_search HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8082

{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": { "permalink": "runewaker-entertainment" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get match with this query:

```
POST /companies/company/_search HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8082

{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": { "permalink": "runewaker" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It appears any permalink with a hyphen in it results in a failed query but I was under the impression that if the mapping for a property has the index set to `not_analyzed` then ElasticSearch wouldn't analyze the field at all.

What should the correct query be?

Thank you

---

**UPDATE:**

getMapping result on the Companies index:

```
{
  "companies" : {
    "company" : {
      "properties" : {
        "company_type" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "entity_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "entity_type" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "node_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "permalink" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described is correct.

I tested and it works as expected. So you probably have some problem with your index. Maybe you indexed the document before you set the mapping?
Try to do it again -
delete your index or create a new one.
do a putMapping with your mapping.
index the document.

The search should work as expected.

Comment: I've tried my configuration on a fresh database server and it still doesn't work

Comment: can attach the result of a getMapping on your index?

Comment: Your field is not "not_analyzed". If it was, it should appear in the mapping. I suggest checking your putMapping call, there's probably something wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise my mapping was erroring when I was creating it due to another problem.